# ORacle before insert Trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER OBU
 BEFORE INSERT ON BOOKING
 REFERENCING NEW AS n
    FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO BOOKINGLOG VALUES(n.HOTELID,n.ROOMNO,n.GUESTID,n.STARTDATE,n.ENDDATE,'SYSTEM',SYSDATE);
 ENG;
 .
 /
```

When i try executing it im getting this error:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
3/4      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting
         one of the following:
         ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
         null pragma raise return select update while with
         <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
         <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock
         insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
         merge pipe purge
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to change ENG; to END;

And, lose the period between that and the /.

To elevate comment to answer: the values in the INSERT statement that reference the table values need to be prefixed with a colon (:).  So, n.HOTELID should be :n.HOTELID, etc.

Comment: oh my bad!now im getting this error Errors for TRIGGER OBU:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
2/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
2/74     PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Comment: Prefix your value references to "n" with a colon (:), e.g., :n.HOTELID